# Rolling statistics with varying window size

Tags: r, rolling-computation

I am managing a stock daily dataset. Here is the sample code:

```
A <- cumsum(rnorm(200))
Date <- Sys.Date() + cumsum(sample(1:5, 200, replace = TRUE)) # unequaly spaced time series
data<-data.frame(Date,A)
data<-data%>%
  mutate(Year_Month=as.yearmon(Date))
```

My objective is to calculate a new monthly variable called B. It is calculated as mean from daily data A over a 12-month period that ends in month. *For example, 2021-07-03 belongs to July of 2021, I need the set the window over previous 12 months, from July of 2020 to June of 2021 and I calculate the average using all daily data A within this window.* Therefore, for [2021-07-03,2021-07-31], the outcome B is the same.

I've tried to use `rollapply` and `runner` function, but the difficulty is the window is not constant since the number of days in each month are not constant. I'd like to achieve this goal under dplyr context.

The expected sample output looks like this:

```
   Date     Year_Month  A   B
2021-07-03  July 2021  3.3  2.3
2021-07-08  July 2021  1.5  2.3
2021-07-11  July 2021  4.3  2.3
...
2021-08-04   Aug 2021  2.2  3.2
2021-08-07   Aug 2021  5.7  3.2
2021-08-09   Aug 2021  4.2  3.2
```

My new dataset is a pure time series with 348 monthly observations:

```
   Date       A
2021-07-01   3.1
2021-08-01   4.5
2021-09-01   5.5
...
2021-10-01   4.4
2021-11-01   2.4
2021-12-01   5.5
```

I am calculating shock by doing AR(2) model over rolling window of 60 months that end in month.The shock in month n+1 is the difference between the actual value of the series and its predicted value (residuals) using the slope coefficients estimated over the preceding 60 months.

I am writing an function and call it inside the slider.

```
AR_2<-function(x){
  arima(x,order=c(1,0,0))$residuals
  
}

MILIQ_unexpected<-MILIQ%>%
  mutate(Shock= slide_index_dbl(A, Date, AR_2, .before = months(60), .after = months(-1), .complete = T))
```

I got the following error:

```
Problem with `mutate()` input `B`.
x In iteration 61, the result of `.f` had size 59, not 1.
i Input `B` is `slide_index_dbl(...)`.
Backtrace:
  1. `%>%`(...)
 11. slider:::stop_not_all_size_one(61L, 59L)
 12. slider:::glubort("In iteration {iteration}, the result of `.f` had size {size}, not 1.")
```

Comment: I use the `slider` package to do this: https://davisvaughan.github.io/slider/. You might want to check it out.

Comment: You are doing it in wrong way again.  For rolling computation i.e. assigning each date a value based on previous n variables (vector of size n) you need a function which returns a scalar (vector of size 1) e.g. mean, sum, etc. and hence rollmean, rollsum etc.  But `arima(rnorm(50), order = c(1,0,0))$residuals` return a vector of length 50.  So how can a vector of size n>1 be assigned to single value unless you further summarise it.  Think of it and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Think like this, there can either be `rollingsum` or `cumsum` but not `rolling-cumsum`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explanation in view of edited question.

- You are doing it in wrong way again.  For rolling computation i.e. assigning each date a value based on previous n variables (vector of size n) you need a function which returns a scalar (vector of size 1) e.g. mean, sum, etc. and hence rollmean, rollsum etc.  But `arima(rnorm(50), order = c(1,0,0))$residuals` return a vector of length 50.  So how can a vector of size n>1 be assigned to single value unless you further summarise it.
- If you further apply some aggregation function say `mean`, your problem can be solved.
- e.g.

```
data %>%
  mutate(dummy = floor_date(Date, 'month'),
         B = slide_index_dbl(A, dummy, \(x) mean(arima(x, order = c(1,0,0))$residuals), .before = months(12), .after = months(-1), .complete = T))
```

This works in my R

---

#### ANSWER

A `slider` approach.  However since slider index works on date fields directly, so instead of using your `Year_month` column I created a dummy column as `floor_date`.

Explanation of Syntax of [slider](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slider/vignettes/slider.html)::`slider_index_dbl`

- It returns a `double` type vector and hence suffix `dbl`
- It also uses a `index` your date column and hence `_index_`
- First argument is vector from which the value/rolling caluculation is to be performed
- second argument is index, Since you are using months instead of date, i created `dummy` column
- third argument is function i.e. `mean` to be calculated
- .`before` is used to take 12 index values preceding the current index
- `.after` is used to exclude current index and hence `-1`
- library(lubridate) may also be loaded as several functions are used here.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

set.seed(123)

A <- cumsum(rnorm(200))
Date <- Sys.Date() + cumsum(sample(1:5, 200, replace = TRUE)) # unequaly spaced time series
data<-data.frame(Date,A)
data<-data%>%
  mutate(Year_Month=as.yearmon(Date))

library(slider)
library(lubridate)

data %>%
  mutate(dummy = floor_date(Date, 'month'),
         B = slide_index_dbl(A, dummy, mean, .before = months(12), .after = months(-1)))

#>           Date           A Year_Month      dummy         B
#> 1   2021-07-02 -0.56047565   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NaN
#> 2   2021-07-03 -0.79065314   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NaN
#> 3   2021-07-08  0.76805518   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NaN
#> 4   2021-07-09  0.83856357   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NaN
#> 5   2021-07-13  0.96785130   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NaN
#> 6   2021-07-15  2.68291629   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NaN
#> 7   2021-07-17  3.14383250   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NaN
#> 8   2021-07-21  1.87877126   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NaN
#> 9   2021-07-22  1.19191841   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NaN
#> 10  2021-07-26  0.74625644   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NaN
#> 11  2021-07-31  1.97033824   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NaN
#> 12  2021-08-05  2.33015207   Aug 2021 2021-08-01 1.1670340
#> 13  2021-08-08  2.73092352   Aug 2021 2021-08-01 1.1670340
#> 14  2021-08-13  2.84160623   Aug 2021 2021-08-01 1.1670340
#> 15  2021-08-18  2.28576510   Aug 2021 2021-08-01 1.1670340
#> 16  2021-08-21  4.07267823   Aug 2021 2021-08-01 1.1670340
#> 17  2021-08-22  4.57052871   Aug 2021 2021-08-01 1.1670340
#> 18  2021-08-25  2.60391156   Aug 2021 2021-08-01 1.1670340
#> 19  2021-08-29  3.30526746   Aug 2021 2021-08-01 1.1670340
#> 20  2021-08-31  2.83247605   Aug 2021 2021-08-01 1.1670340
#> 21  2021-09-05  1.76465234   Sep 2021 2021-09-01 2.0205342
#> 22  2021-09-06  1.54667743   Sep 2021 2021-09-01 2.0205342
#> 23  2021-09-10  0.52067298   Sep 2021 2021-09-01 2.0205342
#> 24  2021-09-13 -0.20821825   Sep 2021 2021-09-01 2.0205342
#> 25  2021-09-14 -0.83325752   Sep 2021 2021-09-01 2.0205342
#> 26  2021-09-16 -2.51995083   Sep 2021 2021-09-01 2.0205342
#> 27  2021-09-19 -1.68216378   Sep 2021 2021-09-01 2.0205342
#> 28  2021-09-22 -1.52879067   Sep 2021 2021-09-01 2.0205342
#> 29  2021-09-23 -2.66692760   Sep 2021 2021-09-01 2.0205342
#> 30  2021-09-25 -1.41311268   Sep 2021 2021-09-01 2.0205342
#> 31  2021-09-26 -0.98664846   Sep 2021 2021-09-01 2.0205342
#> 32  2021-09-28 -1.28171994   Sep 2021 2021-09-01 2.0205342
#> 33  2021-09-30 -0.38659428   Sep 2021 2021-09-01 2.0205342
#> 34  2021-10-02  0.49153921   Oct 2021 2021-10-01 0.9313728
#> 35  2021-10-07  1.31312029   Oct 2021 2021-10-01 0.9313728
#> 36  2021-10-11  2.00176054   Oct 2021 2021-10-01 0.9313728
#> 37  2021-10-15  2.55567820   Oct 2021 2021-10-01 0.9313728
#> 38  2021-10-20  2.49376648   Oct 2021 2021-10-01 0.9313728
#> 39  2021-10-24  2.18780382   Oct 2021 2021-10-01 0.9313728
#> 40  2021-10-25  1.80733282   Oct 2021 2021-10-01 0.9313728
#> 41  2021-10-27  1.11262584   Oct 2021 2021-10-01 0.9313728
#> 42  2021-10-28  0.90470856   Oct 2021 2021-10-01 0.9313728
#> 43  2021-10-30 -0.36068779   Oct 2021 2021-10-01 0.9313728
#> 44  2021-11-02  1.80826818   Nov 2021 2021-11-01 1.0521616
#> 45  2021-11-04  3.01623018   Nov 2021 2021-11-01 1.0521616
#> 46  2021-11-07  1.89312159   Nov 2021 2021-11-01 1.0521616
#> 47  2021-11-08  1.49023676   Nov 2021 2021-11-01 1.0521616
#> 48  2021-11-12  1.02358140   Nov 2021 2021-11-01 1.0521616
#> 49  2021-11-14  1.80354652   Nov 2021 2021-11-01 1.0521616
#> 50  2021-11-17  1.72017745   Nov 2021 2021-11-01 1.0521616
#> 51  2021-11-22  1.97349597   Nov 2021 2021-11-01 1.0521616
#> 52  2021-11-27  1.94494921   Nov 2021 2021-11-01 1.0521616
#> 53  2021-11-30  1.90207876   Nov 2021 2021-11-01 1.0521616
#> 54  2021-12-02  3.27068104   Dec 2021 2021-12-01 1.2041252
#> 55  2021-12-07  3.04491005   Dec 2021 2021-12-01 1.2041252
#> 56  2021-12-11  4.56138066   Dec 2021 2021-12-01 1.2041252
#> 57  2021-12-13  3.01262785   Dec 2021 2021-12-01 1.2041252
#> 58  2021-12-14  3.59724160   Dec 2021 2021-12-01 1.2041252
#> 59  2021-12-18  3.72109585   Dec 2021 2021-12-01 1.2041252
#> 60  2021-12-19  3.93703742   Dec 2021 2021-12-01 1.2041252
#> 61  2021-12-23  4.31667690   Dec 2021 2021-12-01 1.2041252
#> 62  2021-12-28  3.81435345   Dec 2021 2021-12-01 1.2041252
#> 63  2022-01-01  3.48114606   Jan 2022 2022-01-01 1.5660426
#> 64  2022-01-03  2.46257068   Jan 2022 2022-01-01 1.5660426
#> 65  2022-01-05  1.39077945   Jan 2022 2022-01-01 1.5660426
#> 66  2022-01-09  1.69430809   Jan 2022 2022-01-01 1.5660426
#> 67  2022-01-12  2.14251787   Jan 2022 2022-01-01 1.5660426
#> 68  2022-01-17  2.19552210   Jan 2022 2022-01-01 1.5660426
#> 69  2022-01-19  3.11778957   Jan 2022 2022-01-01 1.5660426
#> 70  2022-01-22  5.16787425   Jan 2022 2022-01-01 1.5660426
#> 71  2022-01-25  4.67684309   Jan 2022 2022-01-01 1.5660426
#> 72  2022-01-28  2.36767421   Jan 2022 2022-01-01 1.5660426
#> 73  2022-01-29  3.37341274   Jan 2022 2022-01-01 1.5660426
#> 74  2022-01-30  2.66421197   Jan 2022 2022-01-01 1.5660426
#> 75  2022-02-02  1.97620336   Feb 2022 2022-02-01 1.7814769
#> 76  2022-02-06  3.00177473   Feb 2022 2022-02-01 1.7814769
#> 77  2022-02-10  2.71700172   Feb 2022 2022-02-01 1.7814769
#> 78  2022-02-15  1.49628401   Feb 2022 2022-02-01 1.7814769
#> 79  2022-02-17  1.67758749   Feb 2022 2022-02-01 1.7814769
#> 80  2022-02-19  1.53869613   Feb 2022 2022-02-01 1.7814769
#> 81  2022-02-23  1.54446031   Feb 2022 2022-02-01 1.7814769
#> 82  2022-02-25  1.92974071   Feb 2022 2022-02-01 1.7814769
#> 83  2022-02-26  1.55908068   Feb 2022 2022-02-01 1.7814769
#> 84  2022-03-02  2.20345723   Mar 2022 2022-03-01 1.7984352
#> 85  2022-03-05  1.98297067   Mar 2022 2022-03-01 1.7984352
#> 86  2022-03-06  2.31475263   Mar 2022 2022-03-01 1.7984352
#> 87  2022-03-11  3.41159164   Mar 2022 2022-03-01 1.7984352
#> 88  2022-03-14  3.84677313   Mar 2022 2022-03-01 1.7984352
#> 89  2022-03-18  3.52084155   Mar 2022 2022-03-01 1.7984352
#> 90  2022-03-20  4.66964917   Mar 2022 2022-03-01 1.7984352
#> 91  2022-03-25  5.66315302   Mar 2022 2022-03-01 1.7984352
#> 92  2022-03-30  6.21154998   Mar 2022 2022-03-01 1.7984352
#> 93  2022-04-01  6.45028172   Apr 2022 2022-04-01 1.9901615
#> 94  2022-04-03  5.82237564   Apr 2022 2022-04-01 1.9901615
#> 95  2022-04-05  7.18302809   Apr 2022 2022-04-01 1.9901615
#> 96  2022-04-06  6.58276850   Apr 2022 2022-04-01 1.9901615
#> 97  2022-04-09  8.77010150   Apr 2022 2022-04-01 1.9901615
#> 98  2022-04-13 10.30271212   Apr 2022 2022-04-01 1.9901615
#> 99  2022-04-16 10.06701176   Apr 2022 2022-04-01 1.9901615
#> 100 2022-04-19  9.04059086   Apr 2022 2022-04-01 1.9901615
#> 101 2022-04-22  8.33018430   Apr 2022 2022-04-01 1.9901615
#> 102 2022-04-26  8.58706801   Apr 2022 2022-04-01 1.9901615
#> 103 2022-04-30  8.34037613   Apr 2022 2022-04-01 1.9901615
#> 104 2022-05-03  7.99283353   May 2022 2022-05-01 2.6463239
#> 105 2022-05-07  7.04121496   May 2022 2022-05-01 2.6463239
#> 106 2022-05-09  6.99618724   May 2022 2022-05-01 2.6463239
#> 107 2022-05-12  6.21128277   May 2022 2022-05-01 2.6463239
#> 108 2022-05-16  4.54334083   May 2022 2022-05-01 2.6463239
#> 109 2022-05-18  4.16311431   May 2022 2022-05-01 2.6463239
#> 110 2022-05-19  5.08211092   May 2022 2022-05-01 2.6463239
#> 111 2022-05-22  4.50676396   May 2022 2022-05-01 2.6463239
#> 112 2022-05-26  5.11472828   May 2022 2022-05-01 2.6463239
#> 113 2022-05-27  3.49684557   May 2022 2022-05-01 2.6463239
#> 114 2022-05-28  3.44128361   May 2022 2022-05-01 2.6463239
#> 115 2022-06-01  3.96069081   Jun 2022 2022-06-01 2.9049216
#> 116 2022-06-05  4.26184417   Jun 2022 2022-06-01 2.9049216
#> 117 2022-06-10  4.36752037   Jun 2022 2022-06-01 2.9049216
#> 118 2022-06-11  3.72681436   Jun 2022 2022-06-01 2.9049216
#> 119 2022-06-15  2.87711001   Jun 2022 2022-06-01 2.9049216
#> 120 2022-06-20  1.85298122   Jun 2022 2022-06-01 2.9049216
#> 121 2022-06-23  1.97062782   Jun 2022 2022-06-01 2.9049216
#> 122 2022-06-25  1.02315321   Jun 2022 2022-06-01 2.9049216
#> 123 2022-06-30  0.53259576   Jun 2022 2022-06-01 2.9049216
#> 124 2022-07-04  0.27650357   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.8921496
#> 125 2022-07-08  2.12036558   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.8921496
#> 126 2022-07-09  1.46841567   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.8921496
#> 127 2022-07-12  1.70380225   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.8921496
#> 128 2022-07-15  1.78176310   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.8921496
#> 129 2022-07-18  0.81990646   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.8921496
#> 130 2022-07-23  0.74859838   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.8921496
#> 131 2022-07-25  2.19314923   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.8921496
#> 132 2022-07-30  2.64465329   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.8921496
#> 133 2022-08-01  2.68588621   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.9475552
#> 134 2022-08-02  2.26338938   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.9475552
#> 135 2022-08-06  0.21014215   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.9475552
#> 136 2022-08-08  1.34147937   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.9475552
#> 137 2022-08-10 -0.11916070   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.9475552
#> 138 2022-08-13  0.62078681   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.9475552
#> 139 2022-08-18  2.52989038   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.9475552
#> 140 2022-08-19  1.08599722   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.9475552
#> 141 2022-08-22  1.78778155   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.9475552
#> 142 2022-08-25  1.52558406   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.9475552
#> 143 2022-08-27 -0.04656010   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.9475552
#> 144 2022-09-01 -1.56122775   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.7883422
#> 145 2022-09-02 -3.16276392   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.7883422
#> 146 2022-09-06 -3.69367045   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.7883422
#> 147 2022-09-10 -5.15542603   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.7883422
#> 148 2022-09-11 -4.46750926   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.7883422
#> 149 2022-09-14 -2.36740032   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.7883422
#> 150 2022-09-18 -3.65443079   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.7883422
#> 151 2022-09-22 -2.86669195   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.7883422
#> 152 2022-09-23 -2.09764971   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.7883422
#> 153 2022-09-28 -1.76544713   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.7883422
#> 154 2022-10-01 -2.77382373   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.6820771
#> 155 2022-10-05 -2.89327634   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.6820771
#> 156 2022-10-07 -3.17367168   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.6820771
#> 157 2022-10-10 -2.61068214   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.6820771
#> 158 2022-10-12 -2.98312090   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.6820771
#> 159 2022-10-15 -2.00614751   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.6820771
#> 160 2022-10-18 -2.38072837   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.6820771
#> 161 2022-10-19 -1.32801690   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.6820771
#> 162 2022-10-24 -2.37719391   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.6820771
#> 163 2022-10-28 -3.63734916   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.6820771
#> 164 2022-11-01 -0.39630922   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.3431466
#> 165 2022-11-06 -0.81316681   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.3431466
#> 166 2022-11-09 -0.51493922   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.3431466
#> 167 2022-11-11  0.12163046   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.3431466
#> 168 2022-11-15 -0.36215017   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.3431466
#> 169 2022-11-20  0.15471187   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.3431466
#> 170 2022-11-22  0.52367640   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.3431466
#> 171 2022-11-25  0.30829589   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.3431466
#> 172 2022-11-28  0.37358893   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.3431466
#> 173 2022-11-29  0.33952167   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.3431466
#> 174 2022-12-02  2.46797357   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.1861398
#> 175 2022-12-04  1.72663748   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.1861398
#> 176 2022-12-07  0.63064121   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.1861398
#> 177 2022-12-10  0.66842961   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.1861398
#> 178 2022-12-11  0.97891036   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.1861398
#> 179 2022-12-13  1.41543384   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.1861398
#> 180 2022-12-15  0.95706850   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.1861398
#> 181 2022-12-17 -0.10625763   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.1861398
#> 182 2022-12-21  1.15692755   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.1861398
#> 183 2022-12-22  0.80727716   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.1861398
#> 184 2022-12-27 -0.05823570   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.1861398
#> 185 2023-01-01 -0.29451527   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.9647998
#> 186 2023-01-04 -0.49169117   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.9647998
#> 187 2023-01-07  0.61822912   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.9647998
#> 188 2023-01-12  0.70296641   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.9647998
#> 189 2023-01-13  1.45702020   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.9647998
#> 190 2023-01-17  0.95772818   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.9647998
#> 191 2023-01-19  1.17217349   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.9647998
#> 192 2023-01-24  0.84748758   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.9647998
#> 193 2023-01-28  0.94207111   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.9647998
#> 194 2023-02-02  0.04670775   Feb 2023 2023-02-01 1.7721209
#> 195 2023-02-03 -1.26409378   Feb 2023 2023-02-01 1.7721209
#> 196 2023-02-05  0.73311960   Feb 2023 2023-02-01 1.7721209
#> 197 2023-02-08  1.33382843   Feb 2023 2023-02-01 1.7721209
#> 198 2023-02-09  0.08255706   Feb 2023 2023-02-01 1.7721209
#> 199 2023-02-10 -0.52860885   Feb 2023 2023-02-01 1.7721209
#> 200 2023-02-13 -1.71408894   Feb 2023 2023-02-01 1.7721209
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

As a check of rolling mean, I calculated mean of first 123 rows in excel, which is `2.8921496` and is correctly displayed in `July 2022` rows.

---

As desired in comments, if only complete cases are required -

- use argument `.complete = TRUE`

```
data %>%
  mutate(dummy = floor_date(Date, 'month'),
         B = slide_index_dbl(A, dummy, mean, .before = months(12), .after = months(-1), .complete = T))

          Date           A Year_Month      dummy        B
1   2021-07-03 -0.56047565   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NA
2   2021-07-04 -0.79065314   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NA
3   2021-07-09  0.76805518   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NA
4   2021-07-10  0.83856357   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NA
5   2021-07-14  0.96785130   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NA
6   2021-07-16  2.68291629   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NA
7   2021-07-18  3.14383250   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NA
8   2021-07-22  1.87877126   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NA
9   2021-07-23  1.19191841   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NA
10  2021-07-27  0.74625644   Jul 2021 2021-07-01       NA
11  2021-08-01  1.97033824   Aug 2021 2021-08-01       NA
12  2021-08-06  2.33015207   Aug 2021 2021-08-01       NA
13  2021-08-09  2.73092352   Aug 2021 2021-08-01       NA
14  2021-08-14  2.84160623   Aug 2021 2021-08-01       NA
15  2021-08-19  2.28576510   Aug 2021 2021-08-01       NA
16  2021-08-22  4.07267823   Aug 2021 2021-08-01       NA
17  2021-08-23  4.57052871   Aug 2021 2021-08-01       NA
18  2021-08-26  2.60391156   Aug 2021 2021-08-01       NA
19  2021-08-30  3.30526746   Aug 2021 2021-08-01       NA
20  2021-09-01  2.83247605   Sep 2021 2021-09-01       NA
21  2021-09-06  1.76465234   Sep 2021 2021-09-01       NA
22  2021-09-07  1.54667743   Sep 2021 2021-09-01       NA
23  2021-09-11  0.52067298   Sep 2021 2021-09-01       NA
24  2021-09-14 -0.20821825   Sep 2021 2021-09-01       NA
25  2021-09-15 -0.83325752   Sep 2021 2021-09-01       NA
26  2021-09-17 -2.51995083   Sep 2021 2021-09-01       NA
27  2021-09-20 -1.68216378   Sep 2021 2021-09-01       NA
28  2021-09-23 -1.52879067   Sep 2021 2021-09-01       NA
29  2021-09-24 -2.66692760   Sep 2021 2021-09-01       NA
30  2021-09-26 -1.41311268   Sep 2021 2021-09-01       NA
31  2021-09-27 -0.98664846   Sep 2021 2021-09-01       NA
32  2021-09-29 -1.28171994   Sep 2021 2021-09-01       NA
33  2021-10-01 -0.38659428   Oct 2021 2021-10-01       NA
34  2021-10-03  0.49153921   Oct 2021 2021-10-01       NA
35  2021-10-08  1.31312029   Oct 2021 2021-10-01       NA
36  2021-10-12  2.00176054   Oct 2021 2021-10-01       NA
37  2021-10-16  2.55567820   Oct 2021 2021-10-01       NA
38  2021-10-21  2.49376648   Oct 2021 2021-10-01       NA
39  2021-10-25  2.18780382   Oct 2021 2021-10-01       NA
40  2021-10-26  1.80733282   Oct 2021 2021-10-01       NA
41  2021-10-28  1.11262584   Oct 2021 2021-10-01       NA
42  2021-10-29  0.90470856   Oct 2021 2021-10-01       NA
43  2021-10-31 -0.36068779   Oct 2021 2021-10-01       NA
44  2021-11-03  1.80826818   Nov 2021 2021-11-01       NA
45  2021-11-05  3.01623018   Nov 2021 2021-11-01       NA
46  2021-11-08  1.89312159   Nov 2021 2021-11-01       NA
47  2021-11-09  1.49023676   Nov 2021 2021-11-01       NA
48  2021-11-13  1.02358140   Nov 2021 2021-11-01       NA
49  2021-11-15  1.80354652   Nov 2021 2021-11-01       NA
50  2021-11-18  1.72017745   Nov 2021 2021-11-01       NA
51  2021-11-23  1.97349597   Nov 2021 2021-11-01       NA
52  2021-11-28  1.94494921   Nov 2021 2021-11-01       NA
53  2021-12-01  1.90207876   Dec 2021 2021-12-01       NA
54  2021-12-03  3.27068104   Dec 2021 2021-12-01       NA
55  2021-12-08  3.04491005   Dec 2021 2021-12-01       NA
56  2021-12-12  4.56138066   Dec 2021 2021-12-01       NA
57  2021-12-14  3.01262785   Dec 2021 2021-12-01       NA
58  2021-12-15  3.59724160   Dec 2021 2021-12-01       NA
59  2021-12-19  3.72109585   Dec 2021 2021-12-01       NA
60  2021-12-20  3.93703742   Dec 2021 2021-12-01       NA
61  2021-12-24  4.31667690   Dec 2021 2021-12-01       NA
62  2021-12-29  3.81435345   Dec 2021 2021-12-01       NA
63  2022-01-02  3.48114606   Jan 2022 2022-01-01       NA
64  2022-01-04  2.46257068   Jan 2022 2022-01-01       NA
65  2022-01-06  1.39077945   Jan 2022 2022-01-01       NA
66  2022-01-10  1.69430809   Jan 2022 2022-01-01       NA
67  2022-01-13  2.14251787   Jan 2022 2022-01-01       NA
68  2022-01-18  2.19552210   Jan 2022 2022-01-01       NA
69  2022-01-20  3.11778957   Jan 2022 2022-01-01       NA
70  2022-01-23  5.16787425   Jan 2022 2022-01-01       NA
71  2022-01-26  4.67684309   Jan 2022 2022-01-01       NA
72  2022-01-29  2.36767421   Jan 2022 2022-01-01       NA
73  2022-01-30  3.37341274   Jan 2022 2022-01-01       NA
74  2022-01-31  2.66421197   Jan 2022 2022-01-01       NA
75  2022-02-03  1.97620336   Feb 2022 2022-02-01       NA
76  2022-02-07  3.00177473   Feb 2022 2022-02-01       NA
77  2022-02-11  2.71700172   Feb 2022 2022-02-01       NA
78  2022-02-16  1.49628401   Feb 2022 2022-02-01       NA
79  2022-02-18  1.67758749   Feb 2022 2022-02-01       NA
80  2022-02-20  1.53869613   Feb 2022 2022-02-01       NA
81  2022-02-24  1.54446031   Feb 2022 2022-02-01       NA
82  2022-02-26  1.92974071   Feb 2022 2022-02-01       NA
83  2022-02-27  1.55908068   Feb 2022 2022-02-01       NA
84  2022-03-03  2.20345723   Mar 2022 2022-03-01       NA
85  2022-03-06  1.98297067   Mar 2022 2022-03-01       NA
86  2022-03-07  2.31475263   Mar 2022 2022-03-01       NA
87  2022-03-12  3.41159164   Mar 2022 2022-03-01       NA
88  2022-03-15  3.84677313   Mar 2022 2022-03-01       NA
89  2022-03-19  3.52084155   Mar 2022 2022-03-01       NA
90  2022-03-21  4.66964917   Mar 2022 2022-03-01       NA
91  2022-03-26  5.66315302   Mar 2022 2022-03-01       NA
92  2022-03-31  6.21154998   Mar 2022 2022-03-01       NA
93  2022-04-02  6.45028172   Apr 2022 2022-04-01       NA
94  2022-04-04  5.82237564   Apr 2022 2022-04-01       NA
95  2022-04-06  7.18302809   Apr 2022 2022-04-01       NA
96  2022-04-07  6.58276850   Apr 2022 2022-04-01       NA
97  2022-04-10  8.77010150   Apr 2022 2022-04-01       NA
98  2022-04-14 10.30271212   Apr 2022 2022-04-01       NA
99  2022-04-17 10.06701176   Apr 2022 2022-04-01       NA
100 2022-04-20  9.04059086   Apr 2022 2022-04-01       NA
101 2022-04-23  8.33018430   Apr 2022 2022-04-01       NA
102 2022-04-27  8.58706801   Apr 2022 2022-04-01       NA
103 2022-05-01  8.34037613   May 2022 2022-05-01       NA
104 2022-05-04  7.99283353   May 2022 2022-05-01       NA
105 2022-05-08  7.04121496   May 2022 2022-05-01       NA
106 2022-05-10  6.99618724   May 2022 2022-05-01       NA
107 2022-05-13  6.21128277   May 2022 2022-05-01       NA
108 2022-05-17  4.54334083   May 2022 2022-05-01       NA
109 2022-05-19  4.16311431   May 2022 2022-05-01       NA
110 2022-05-20  5.08211092   May 2022 2022-05-01       NA
111 2022-05-23  4.50676396   May 2022 2022-05-01       NA
112 2022-05-27  5.11472828   May 2022 2022-05-01       NA
113 2022-05-28  3.49684557   May 2022 2022-05-01       NA
114 2022-05-29  3.44128361   May 2022 2022-05-01       NA
115 2022-06-02  3.96069081   Jun 2022 2022-06-01       NA
116 2022-06-06  4.26184417   Jun 2022 2022-06-01       NA
117 2022-06-11  4.36752037   Jun 2022 2022-06-01       NA
118 2022-06-12  3.72681436   Jun 2022 2022-06-01       NA
119 2022-06-16  2.87711001   Jun 2022 2022-06-01       NA
120 2022-06-21  1.85298122   Jun 2022 2022-06-01       NA
121 2022-06-24  1.97062782   Jun 2022 2022-06-01       NA
122 2022-06-26  1.02315321   Jun 2022 2022-06-01       NA
123 2022-07-01  0.53259576   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.911490
124 2022-07-05  0.27650357   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.911490
125 2022-07-09  2.12036558   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.911490
126 2022-07-10  1.46841567   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.911490
127 2022-07-13  1.70380225   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.911490
128 2022-07-16  1.78176310   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.911490
129 2022-07-19  0.81990646   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.911490
130 2022-07-24  0.74859838   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.911490
131 2022-07-26  2.19314923   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.911490
132 2022-07-31  2.64465329   Jul 2022 2022-07-01 2.911490
133 2022-08-02  2.68588621   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.939545
134 2022-08-03  2.26338938   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.939545
135 2022-08-07  0.21014215   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.939545
136 2022-08-09  1.34147937   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.939545
137 2022-08-11 -0.11916070   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.939545
138 2022-08-14  0.62078681   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.939545
139 2022-08-19  2.52989038   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.939545
140 2022-08-20  1.08599722   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.939545
141 2022-08-23  1.78778155   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.939545
142 2022-08-26  1.52558406   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.939545
143 2022-08-28 -0.04656010   Aug 2022 2022-08-01 2.939545
144 2022-09-02 -1.56122775   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.788698
145 2022-09-03 -3.16276392   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.788698
146 2022-09-07 -3.69367045   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.788698
147 2022-09-11 -5.15542603   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.788698
148 2022-09-12 -4.46750926   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.788698
149 2022-09-15 -2.36740032   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.788698
150 2022-09-19 -3.65443079   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.788698
151 2022-09-23 -2.86669195   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.788698
152 2022-09-24 -2.09764971   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.788698
153 2022-09-29 -1.76544713   Sep 2022 2022-09-01 2.788698
154 2022-10-02 -2.77382373   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.656716
155 2022-10-06 -2.89327634   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.656716
156 2022-10-08 -3.17367168   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.656716
157 2022-10-11 -2.61068214   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.656716
158 2022-10-13 -2.98312090   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.656716
159 2022-10-16 -2.00614751   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.656716
160 2022-10-19 -2.38072837   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.656716
161 2022-10-20 -1.32801690   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.656716
162 2022-10-25 -2.37719391   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.656716
163 2022-10-29 -3.63734916   Oct 2022 2022-10-01 2.656716
164 2022-11-02 -0.39630922   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.343147
165 2022-11-07 -0.81316681   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.343147
166 2022-11-10 -0.51493922   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.343147
167 2022-11-12  0.12163046   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.343147
168 2022-11-16 -0.36215017   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.343147
169 2022-11-21  0.15471187   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.343147
170 2022-11-23  0.52367640   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.343147
171 2022-11-26  0.30829589   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.343147
172 2022-11-29  0.37358893   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.343147
173 2022-11-30  0.33952167   Nov 2022 2022-11-01 2.343147
174 2022-12-03  2.46797357   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.183792
175 2022-12-05  1.72663748   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.183792
176 2022-12-08  0.63064121   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.183792
177 2022-12-11  0.66842961   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.183792
178 2022-12-12  0.97891036   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.183792
179 2022-12-14  1.41543384   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.183792
180 2022-12-16  0.95706850   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.183792
181 2022-12-18 -0.10625763   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.183792
182 2022-12-22  1.15692755   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.183792
183 2022-12-23  0.80727716   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.183792
184 2022-12-28 -0.05823570   Dec 2022 2022-12-01 2.183792
185 2023-01-02 -0.29451527   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.964800
186 2023-01-05 -0.49169117   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.964800
187 2023-01-08  0.61822912   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.964800
188 2023-01-13  0.70296641   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.964800
189 2023-01-14  1.45702020   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.964800
190 2023-01-18  0.95772818   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.964800
191 2023-01-20  1.17217349   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.964800
192 2023-01-25  0.84748758   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.964800
193 2023-01-29  0.94207111   Jan 2023 2023-01-01 1.964800
194 2023-02-03  0.04670775   Feb 2023 2023-02-01 1.772121
195 2023-02-04 -1.26409378   Feb 2023 2023-02-01 1.772121
196 2023-02-06  0.73311960   Feb 2023 2023-02-01 1.772121
197 2023-02-09  1.33382843   Feb 2023 2023-02-01 1.772121
198 2023-02-10  0.08255706   Feb 2023 2023-02-01 1.772121
199 2023-02-11 -0.52860885   Feb 2023 2023-02-01 1.772121
200 2023-02-14 -1.71408894   Feb 2023 2023-02-01 1.772121
```

If you want to use custom function inside `slider` you may use invisible function style there.  Like

```
data %>%
  mutate(dummy = floor_date(Date, 'month'),
         B = slide_index_dbl(A, dummy, \(x) mean(x, na.rm=T), .before = months(12), .after = months(-1), .complete = T))
```

Comment: Thanks. The only confusion for me is that, for example, for any data from 2021-08-05 to 2021-08-31, the date used will be from 2020-08 to 2021-07 and I understand this is achieved by set before(12) and after(-1). However, I do not even have data available during this window in my sample code, how do you get the mean of 1.1670340?

Comment: @derek that can also be taken care of.  In the instant case, the calculation has started for incomplete cases i.e. when there is at least one month to calculate the desired mean.  Use another argument `.complete = TRUE` if you don't want to include incomplete (less than 12 months) in calculation

Comment: Thank you sir, that really helps. One last question is how can I custmize function in slider, for example, I'd like to count the non-NA observations, sum(!is.na(A)), or mean(A,na.rm=T) or any other more complicated functions.

Comment: Thanks Anil! I am new to R and you are a life saver. Please see the edited question as I am doing a AR model inside the slider.

Comment: @derek, I think you should propose another/separate question, because the error relates working and output of `arima` and not to rolling-computation.  The error tells us that your custom function output is not as same length as that of input `x`

Comment: I understand your point. The reason of my issue is I misunderstand the original procedure. I need to predict the new value using coefficient and calculate the difference between it and actual one. The length of output should be just 1. Please see my new question I just posted. Hope you can help me out. Thank Anil.

Answer (score 2):

These alternatives only use packages that it seems you are already using except for (1) which also uses sqldf.  (2) could be easily modified to remove dplyr by using transform instead of mutate and making corresponding alterations.

When using variable windows lengths it is generally desirable to also show the number of points that contribute to each so we have added that to each solution below.  If you don't need that then the solutions could be slightly shorter.

Note that `Year_Month - 1/12` is the prior year/month and `Year_Month - 1` is the year-ago year/month.

**1) SQL** This can be expressed by a self join with the indicated condition. dplyr joins do not support this and it is a lot easier to just use sql which can express this elegantly.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(sqldf)

res <- data %>% 
   do( sqldf("select a.*, avg(b.A) B, count(b.A) n
    from [.] a
    left join [.] b on b.Year_Month between a.Year_Month - 1. and a.Year_Month - 1./12.
    group by a.rowid") )


tail(res)
##           Date           A Year_Month        B   n
## 195 2023-02-03 -1.26409378   Feb 2023 1.772121 119
## 196 2023-02-05  0.73311960   Feb 2023 1.772121 119
## 197 2023-02-08  1.33382843   Feb 2023 1.772121 119
## 198 2023-02-09  0.08255706   Feb 2023 1.772121 119
## 199 2023-02-10 -0.52860885   Feb 2023 1.772121 119
## 200 2023-02-13 -1.71408894   Feb 2023 1.772121 119
```

To check we show the starting row of each year/month:

```
data[!duplicated(data$Year_Month), ]
##           Date           A Year_Month
## 1   2021-07-02 -0.56047565   Jul 2021
## 12  2021-08-05  2.33015207   Aug 2021
## 21  2021-09-05  1.76465234   Sep 2021
## 34  2021-10-02  0.49153921   Oct 2021
## 44  2021-11-02  1.80826818   Nov 2021
## 54  2021-12-02  3.27068104   Dec 2021
## 63  2022-01-01  3.48114606   Jan 2022
## 75  2022-02-02  1.97620336   Feb 2022
## 84  2022-03-02  2.20345723   Mar 2022
## 93  2022-04-01  6.45028172   Apr 2022
## 104 2022-05-03  7.99283353   May 2022
## 115 2022-06-01  3.96069081   Jun 2022
## 124 2022-07-04  0.27650357   Jul 2022
## 133 2022-08-01  2.68588621   Aug 2022
## 144 2022-09-01 -1.56122775   Sep 2022
## 154 2022-10-01 -2.77382373   Oct 2022
## 164 2022-11-01 -0.39630922   Nov 2022
## 174 2022-12-02  2.46797357   Dec 2022
## 185 2023-01-01 -0.29451527   Jan 2023
## 194 2023-02-02  0.04670775   Feb 2023
```

so the last row should be the mean of A between rows 75 and 193 inclusive and 193-75+1 = 119 points contribute:

```
mean(data$A[75:193])
## [1] 1.772121
```

**2) sapply**  We can also define an indexes function which given a row number generates the indexes to average over and then use that to generate the means and counts.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

indexes <- function(ix, ym, x = ym[ix]) which(ym >= x-1 & ym <= x - 1/12)
res2 <- data %>%
  do({ indexList <- lapply(1:nrow(.), indexes, .$Year_Month)
       mutate(., B = sapply(indexList, function(x) mean(A[x])), n = lengths(indexList))
  })

all.equal(res, res2) 
## [1] TRUE
```

**3) rollapply**  Note that rollapply is not limited to constant window sizes as the width argument can be a vector of widths or a list of offsets. See ?rollapply for more information on that function. Using indexes from (2) which creates a list of indexes subtract the current index from each one to give offsets and then use that as the rollapply width argument.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

res3 <- data %>%
  do({ width <- lapply(1:nrow(.), function(ix) indexes(ix, .$Year_Month) - ix)
       mutate(., B = rollapply(A, width, mean), n = lengths(width))
  })

all.equal(res3, res)
## [1] TRUE
```

**4) rollapply - 2**  In (3) we used a variable window size directly with rollapply but another way is to reduce the problem to a fixed window size and then use rollapply on that.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

roll <- function(x, fill=NA) rollapply(x, list(-seq(12)), sum, partial=TRUE, fill=fill)

summary <- data %>%
  group_by(Year_Month) %>%
  summarize(s = sum(A), n = n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(s = roll(s), n = roll(n, fill = 0), B = s/n) %>%
  select(Year_Month, B, n)

res4 <- data %>%
  left_join(summary, by = "Year_Month")

all.equal(res, res4)
## [1] TRUE
```

### Note

Because the question used random numbers without set.seed, the library
statements are missing and it gives a different result each day due to the use of Sys.Date() its code is not reproducible so to  be clear we use:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
set.seed(123)

A <- cumsum(rnorm(200))
Date <- as.Date("2021-06-29") + cumsum(sample(5, 200, replace = TRUE))
data <- data.frame(Date, A) %>% mutate(Year_Month = as.yearmon(Date))
```

Comment: Thank you ！I'd like to manage under dplyr becase my data is actually panel, so I need to group_by(ID).’

Comment: All approaches use dplyr pipelines. Have now wrapped {...} in do(...) so that dot refers to the current group.  Also added 4th approach.

Comment: Hi! Are you interested in answering my another related question I just posed recently?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck perfect, this works. Would you mind adding a datatable solution? Usually it is a bit faster on large data sets. I tried to convert it from dplyr, but something doesn't seem to work. I am not very familiar with dplyr

Comment: dplyr works with data.tables too.